# Adding the appropriate elements in SectionStackSections

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I'm trying to build a similar menu like in http://www.gwt-ext.com/demo/#menuButton. But i am using the SmartGWT instead of GWT-Ext and GWT Designer in Eclipse. I have built the SectionStack and add to it 3 sections. My problem is that i do not know what components to add in each section to get the selected items as in the example 'Showcase Explorer' menu of the link. Like the example i want to fill each section with several text lines but if i add just Label components then there are not selectable like in the example (when you view the menu in accordion mode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you use http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#menus_category_treebinding this menu instead?

Comment: ok thanks for the reply, i think the question was not good at all, but i have found a way to implement my initial design